# Use Phoenix's `Socket` JS module in a separate JS project

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a separate JS UI app which connects to Phoenix server via Phoenix's Socket JS module.

What is the best way to import the Socket module into my project? Are there any `npm` which contains only Phoenix JS modules?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is on the roadmap to be extracted into an npm package, however there is no timeline

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/827

> Folks, the client will be extracted when I have time to prioritize it. Until then, hang tight.
>
> (9 days ago)

Until it is extracted, your best bet is to import it into your project. The file is available at [on GitHub](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/0e4e4b2db946cb7cc441eb56e7be4c82704025c9/web/static/js/phoenix.js).